Android Media3 Exoplayer : How to set different cookie for each HlsMediaSource while call addMediaItem() function?
Recently I try to migrate standalone Exoplayer SDK to Media3 Exoplayer.
While I implement MediaLibrayService and the callback listener, I can play normal mp3 url through MediaController.setMediaItem().
But my project needs to play each HLS(.m3u8) source with different cookies.
I try to override onAddMediaItems to set cookie with each Media Item and it's not working and kept received Caused by: androidx.media3.datasource.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403.
Below is part of my code. Hope someone can give me some advices to solved this problem.
MediaLibraryService
override fun onAddMediaItems(
    mediaSession: MediaSession,
    controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo,
    mediaItems: MutableList<MediaItem>,
): ListenableFuture<MutableList<MediaItem>> {
    val updatedMediaItems = mediaItems.map {
        val cookie = it.requestMetadata.extras?.getString("COOKIE") ?: ""
        val httpSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().apply {
            setDefaultRequestProperties(mapOf("Cookie" to cookie))
            setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; SM-A136B Build/SP1A.210812.016; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/130.0.6723.107 Mobile Safari/537.36")
            setConnectTimeoutMs(DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
            setReadTimeoutMs(DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
            setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true)
        }
        httpSourceFactory.createDataSource().setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie)
        val mediaSourceFactory = HlsMediaSource.Factory(httpSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(it)

        (mediaSession.player as? ExoPlayer)?.setMediaSource(mediaSourceFactory)

        it
    }.toMutableList()
    return Futures.immediateFuture(updatedMediaItems)
}

PlayerActivity
private fun playAudio() {
    val controller = this.controller ?: return
    val cookie: String = getString(
        R.string.cookies_format,
        "Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ga______",
        "eyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    )
    val cookieBundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString("COOKIE", cookie)
    }

    val mediaMetadata = MediaMetadata.Builder()
        .setAlbumTitle("SoundHelix")
        .setDisplayTitle("Song 1")
        .build()

    val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri(
            "https://test.net/media/out/11111/hls/11/11111.m3u8"
        )
        .setRequestMetadata(
            RequestMetadata.Builder()
                .setExtras(cookieBundle).build()
        )
        .setMediaMetadata(mediaMetadata)
        .build()

    controller.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    controller.prepare()
    controller.play()
}

